# Selecting random tuple from bag

Tags: apache-pig

Is it possible to (efficiently) select a random tuple from a bag in pig? 
I can just take the first result of a bag (as it is unordered), but in my case I need a proper random selection.
One (not efficient) solution is counting the number of tuples in the bag, take a random number within that range, loop through the bag, and stop whenever the number of iterations matches my random number. Does anyone know of faster/better ways to do this?

Comment: How would you "loop through the bag"?

Comment: A = FOREACH myBag {
    --do stuff
};
Actually havent implemented this approach, so I'm not sure whether this solution would work as well

Comment: That won't work; you can't keep track of the number of iterations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use RANDOM(), ORDER and LIMIT in a nested FOREACH statement to select one element with the smallest random number:

```
inpt = load 'group.txt' as (id:int, c1:bytearray, c2:bytearray);
groups = group inpt by id;
randoms = foreach groups {
    rnds = foreach inpt generate *, RANDOM() as rnd; -- assign random number to each row in the bag
    ordered_rnds = order rnds by rnd;
    one_tuple = limit ordered_rnds 1; -- select tuple with the smallest random number
    generate group as id, one_tuple;
};
```

dump randoms;

**INPUT:**

```
1   a   r
1   a   t
1   b   r
1   b   4
1   e   4
1   h   4
1   k   t
2   k   k
2   j   j
3   a   r
3   e   l
3   j   l
4   a   r
4   b   t
4   b   g
4   h   b
4   j   d
5   h   k
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
(1,{(1,b,r,0.05172709255901231)})
(2,{(2,k,k,0.14351660053632986)})
(3,{(3,e,l,0.0854104195792681)})
(4,{(4,h,b,8.906013598960483E-4)})
(5,{(5,h,k,0.6219490873384448)})
```

If you run "dump randoms;" multiple times, you should get different results for each run.

Writing a UDF might give you better performance as you do not need to do secondary sort on random within the bag.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to do this myself, and found surprisingly that a very simple answer seems to work, to get about 10% of an alias A:

B = filter A by RANDOM() < 0.1

Comment: This is available via the sample function as well: `B = SAMPLE A 0.1`

Comment: As a side note, I've noticed some unusual behaviour when using `RANDOM()` followed by `SPLIT` (or a regular `FILTER`). In this case, partitioning your dataset `A` (into `A1` and `A2` for example) requires to store your dataset first after applying the `RANDOM()` function. Then one can reload the result and split it using `SPLIT` or `FILTER` in order to obtain a 'true' partition. Otherwise, you might end up with 2 sets such that `|A1| + |A2| < |A|`